# Why does my Twitter profile keep reverting to the old details?

Tags: twitter, google-account-profile

Thank you for this forum. Twitter is not responding, so I thought I'd ask here. Since last December, when I changed my business name and location, Twitter (and my Google My Business accounts) keep reverting to my previous brand details - literally everything except the Handle reverts to the earlier brand! I thought maybe 411.ca rep got annoyed that I dropped their paid service, and keeps doing it on their backend - one person said they stopped, but no response since - but I don't see why that would be the case.

Can anyone share a permanent solution to this, or shed some light? Thank you! I hope you and yours are doing well during this period of global change.